# Woman going out on Shabbath with a "Moch"

Tags: lomdus, niddah, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, maseches-shabbos

The Gemara (שבת, פ׳ במה בהמה) has lengthy discussions about animals going out with covers tied to their udders or other extremities, and repeatedly (briefly) mentions a Zav wearing a sac to catch his discharge. What about a Zavah or a Niddah with a "[Moch](http://www.yoatzot.org/topic.php?id=47)"? Is there any Issur of carrying, or a rabbinic prohibition lest she later come to carry it? It seems to me that this is a different sort of device (not tied on), but serving the same purpose as the Zav's, and because it's not tied it could come loose, which is the concern mentioned for the other cases. But (as far as I see so far) it isn't mentioned.

Comment: The Zav's sack seems more like a tampon than a moch. A moch isn't there for hygienic reasons.

Comment: Yay! Yoatzot agree(s) with me http://www.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=482

Comment: His is also for checking, no?

Comment: Can you edit in a more specific daf (or range of dapim) where this discussion is found?

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood the Zav case. Yes Rashi says it's for checking so should be parallel to Moch and we see both are prohibited to carry.

Comment: This is mentioned explicitly by the Mishna, Shabbat 6:5. Have you looked at the gemara there?

Comment: My apologies to doubleaa and @msh210. I wrote this on mobile as I was preparing for Shabbath, so I could not add additional detail.

Comment: ^^^ same as above to @ShimonbM. As for your question to my question, that is a different "Moch". That's a tampon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Rav Moshe* Feinstein forbade it ([*IgM*, *OC* 3, 47](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=346)).

Comment: A tip of the hat to [The Rebbetzin's Husband](http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.com/2011/12/moch-dachuk-where-there-is-no-eruv.html) for pointing me to this _IgM_.

Comment: It's important to note though that he does suggest a possible heter, but prefers not to rely on it.

Comment: @doubleaa, interestingly, whatever R' Moshe's reasons for rejecting the Heter (I haven't read the Teshuvah yet), Yoatzot (thanks for "suggesting" that site for this discussion, btw) recommends that a woman with a compelling need to go out seek a Heter to skip the "Moch" rather that a Heter to use one without an 'Eruv.

Comment: @SethJ That sounds pretty reasonable as carrying on Shabbat would be an Issur Sekilah (and I agree with RMF that his svara is kinda weak), whereas in _most_ cases performing a Moch Dachuk is somewhat of a chumra.

Comment: @doubleaa, except that an 'Eiruv only works if carrying would be an Isur DeRabbanan.

Comment: @SethJ So? Are you asking about carrying in a place with an Eruv or carrying in a place without an Eruv?